# How to enable tick labels on DateSlider?

Tags: bokeh

This doesnt seem to work. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter

slider = DateSlider(
title = 'Date',
start = date(2020,1,1), 
end = date(2020,8,1), 
step = 31*24*60*60*1000, 
value = date(2020,1,1), 
format=DatetimeTickFormatter(hours=["%d %b %Y"], days=["%d %b %Y"], months=["%d %b %Y"], years=["%d %b %Y"])
        )
```

EDIT #1:
After suggestion from Eugene, I modified the code to this:

```
format = "%d %b %Y"
```

but still dont see the tick labels. Below is the screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have created https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/10468 for this.

In the meantime, since all your format strings are the same, you can just pass the format directly:

```py
slider = DateSlider(..., format="%d %b %Y")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tired it but still cant see tick labels on my slider. I have edited the OP to include screenshot. Please have a look.

Comment: Seems like I have misunderstood you. AFAIK Bokeh Sliders have never had ticks. The `format` is there to format the current value. Bokeh uses `noUiSlider` under the hood which has the `pips` property that adds "ticks", so it should be possible to add this feature to Bokeh. If you really need this functionality, please comment on https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6899 (and reopen it if you have the permission).